# Tracking how much time particular task spends in a lane - Kanboard

Tags: kanban, pm-software, kanban-board

In Kanboard (https://kanboard.net/) I can display average time all tasks spent in particular column:

[image: Average time tasks spend in lanes]

However, I need information on how much time **particular task** spent in each lane.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have experience with the tool, but I hope the following links are useful.

[kanboard - transitions](https://docs.kanboard.org/en/latest/user_guide/tasks.html#task-transitions)

[kanboard - time tracking](https://docs.kanboard.org/en/latest/user_guide/time_tracking.html)

Comment: There's a traditional RDBMS under the hood. The "transitions" from the first link must be stored in it somewhere. A little bit of elbow grease and it should be possible to query directly. https://kanboard.net/documentation/mysql-configuration

Answer (score 1):

If your question is not specific to this tool, I'd recommend using ActionableAgile. To my knowledge this is the most powerful flow analytics software available out there. [Kanbanize](https://kanbanize.com) wraps their functionality and integrates seamlessly. For more information, check this: [Flow analytics in Kanbanize](https://kanbanize.com/kanban-resources/kanban-analytics/monte-carlo-simulation/)